# Accuracy of deep tensorflow model not changing

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been trying to create an image classifier model using tensorflow. I just have two classes: class_a and class_b represented in code as 0 and 1.

Here is my model code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, AveragePooling2D, Concatenate, GlobalAveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization, ReLU, Add

def googlenet(input_shape, n_classes):
  
  def inception_block(x, f):
    t1 = Conv2D(f[0], 1, activation='relu')(x)
    
    t2 = Conv2D(f[1], 1, activation='relu')(x)
    t2 = Conv2D(f[2], 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(t2)
    
    t3 = Conv2D(f[3], 1, activation='relu')(x)
    t3 = Conv2D(f[4], 5, padding='same', activation='relu')(t3)
    
    t4 = MaxPool2D(3, 1, padding='same')(x)
    t4 = Conv2D(f[5], 1, activation='relu')(t4)
    
    output = Concatenate()([t1, t2, t3, t4])
    return output
  
  
  inp = Input(input_shape)
  
  x = Conv2D(64, 7, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(inp)
  x = MaxPool2D(3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  
  x = Conv2D(64, 1, activation='relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(192, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = MaxPool2D(3, strides=2)(x)
  
  x = inception_block(x, [64, 96, 128, 16, 32, 32])
  x = inception_block(x, [128, 128, 192, 32, 96, 64])
  x = MaxPool2D(3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  
  x = inception_block(x, [192, 96, 208, 16, 48, 64])
  x = inception_block(x, [160, 112, 224, 24, 64, 64])
  x = inception_block(x, [128, 128, 256, 24, 64, 64])
  x = inception_block(x, [112, 144, 288, 32, 64, 64])
  x = inception_block(x, [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128])
  x = MaxPool2D(3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)

  x = inception_block(x, [256, 160, 320, 32, 128, 128])
  x = inception_block(x, [384, 192, 384, 48, 128, 128])
  
  x = AveragePooling2D(7, strides=1)(x)
  x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
  
  x = Flatten()(x)
  output = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
  
  model = Model(inp, output)
  return model


input_shape = (256, 256, 3)
n_classes = 1


model1 = googlenet(input_shape, n_classes)
model1.compile('Adam', loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
model1.summary()
```

Sample output of above code:

```
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_4 (InputLayer)           [(None, 256, 256, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_231 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 64  9472        ['input_4[0][0]']                
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_15 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 64, 64, 64)  0           ['conv2d_231[0][0]']             
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_232 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 64)   4160        ['max_pooling2d_15[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_233 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 192)  110784      ['conv2d_232[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_16 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 31, 31, 192)  0          ['conv2d_233[0][0]']             
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_235 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 96)   18528       ['max_pooling2d_16[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_237 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 16)   3088        ['max_pooling2d_16[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_17 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 31, 31, 192)  0          ['max_pooling2d_16[0][0]']       
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_234 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 64)   12352       ['max_pooling2d_16[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_236 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 128)  110720      ['conv2d_235[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_238 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 32)   12832       ['conv2d_237[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_239 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 32)   6176        ['max_pooling2d_17[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_67 (Concatenate)   (None, 31, 31, 256)  0           ['conv2d_234[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_236[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_238[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_239[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_241 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 128)  32896       ['concatenate_67[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_243 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 32)   8224        ['concatenate_67[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_18 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 31, 31, 256)  0          ['concatenate_67[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_240 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 128)  32896       ['concatenate_67[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_242 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 192)  221376      ['conv2d_241[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_244 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 96)   76896       ['conv2d_243[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_245 (Conv2D)            (None, 31, 31, 64)   16448       ['max_pooling2d_18[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_68 (Concatenate)   (None, 31, 31, 480)  0           ['conv2d_240[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_242[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_244[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_245[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_19 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 16, 16, 480)  0          ['concatenate_68[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_247 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 96)   46176       ['max_pooling2d_19[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_249 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 16)   7696        ['max_pooling2d_19[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_20 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 16, 16, 480)  0          ['max_pooling2d_19[0][0]']       
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_246 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 192)  92352       ['max_pooling2d_19[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_248 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 208)  179920      ['conv2d_247[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_250 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 48)   19248       ['conv2d_249[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_251 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 64)   30784       ['max_pooling2d_20[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_69 (Concatenate)   (None, 16, 16, 512)  0           ['conv2d_246[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_248[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_250[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_251[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_253 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 112)  57456       ['concatenate_69[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_255 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 24)   12312       ['concatenate_69[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_21 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 16, 16, 512)  0          ['concatenate_69[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_252 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 160)  82080       ['concatenate_69[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_254 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 224)  226016      ['conv2d_253[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_256 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 64)   38464       ['conv2d_255[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_257 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 64)   32832       ['max_pooling2d_21[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_70 (Concatenate)   (None, 16, 16, 512)  0           ['conv2d_252[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_254[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_256[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_257[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_259 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)  65664       ['concatenate_70[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_261 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 24)   12312       ['concatenate_70[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_22 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 16, 16, 512)  0          ['concatenate_70[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_258 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)  65664       ['concatenate_70[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_260 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 256)  295168      ['conv2d_259[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_262 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 64)   38464       ['conv2d_261[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_263 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 64)   32832       ['max_pooling2d_22[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_71 (Concatenate)   (None, 16, 16, 512)  0           ['conv2d_258[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_260[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_262[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_263[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_265 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 144)  73872       ['concatenate_71[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_267 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 32)   16416       ['concatenate_71[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_23 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 16, 16, 512)  0          ['concatenate_71[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_264 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 112)  57456       ['concatenate_71[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_266 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 288)  373536      ['conv2d_265[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_268 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 64)   51264       ['conv2d_267[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_269 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 64)   32832       ['max_pooling2d_23[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_72 (Concatenate)   (None, 16, 16, 528)  0           ['conv2d_264[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_266[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_268[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_269[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_271 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 160)  84640       ['concatenate_72[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_273 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 32)   16928       ['concatenate_72[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_24 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 16, 16, 528)  0          ['concatenate_72[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_270 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 256)  135424      ['concatenate_72[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_272 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 320)  461120      ['conv2d_271[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_274 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)  102528      ['conv2d_273[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_275 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)  67712       ['max_pooling2d_24[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_73 (Concatenate)   (None, 16, 16, 832)  0           ['conv2d_270[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_272[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_274[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_275[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_25 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 8, 8, 832)   0           ['concatenate_73[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_277 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 160)    133280      ['max_pooling2d_25[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_279 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 32)     26656       ['max_pooling2d_25[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_26 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 8, 8, 832)   0           ['max_pooling2d_25[0][0]']       
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_276 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 256)    213248      ['max_pooling2d_25[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_278 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 320)    461120      ['conv2d_277[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_280 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 128)    102528      ['conv2d_279[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_281 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 128)    106624      ['max_pooling2d_26[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_74 (Concatenate)   (None, 8, 8, 832)    0           ['conv2d_276[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_278[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_280[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_281[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_283 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 192)    159936      ['concatenate_74[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_285 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 48)     39984       ['concatenate_74[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_27 (MaxPooling2D  (None, 8, 8, 832)   0           ['concatenate_74[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_282 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 384)    319872      ['concatenate_74[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_284 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 384)    663936      ['conv2d_283[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_286 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 128)    153728      ['conv2d_285[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_287 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 128)    106624      ['max_pooling2d_27[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_75 (Concatenate)   (None, 8, 8, 1024)   0           ['conv2d_282[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_284[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_286[0][0]',             
                                                                  'conv2d_287[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 average_pooling2d_5 (AveragePo  (None, 2, 2, 1024)  0           ['concatenate_75[0][0]']         
 oling2D)                                                                                         
                                                                                                  
 dropout_1 (Dropout)            (None, 2, 2, 1024)   0           ['average_pooling2d_5[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 flatten_1 (Flatten)            (None, 4096)         0           ['dropout_1[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)                (None, 1)            4097        ['flatten_1[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 5,977,649
Trainable params: 5,977,649
Non-trainable params: 0
```

But whenever I am executing the following lines below to train my model,
I find that even though my loss is decreasing minutely my accuracy is completely fixed:

```
logdir='logs'    # Being stored in logs folder/directory
tensorboard_callback1 = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
hist1 = model1.fit(train, epochs=5, validation_data=val, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback1])
print(hist1.history)
```

The Output of above code is:

```
Epoch 1/5
163/163 [==============================] - 29s 163ms/step - loss: 0.5340 - accuracy: 0.1629 - val_loss: 0.4640 - val_accuracy: 0.1727
Epoch 2/5
163/163 [==============================] - 29s 174ms/step - loss: 0.4477 - accuracy: 0.1629 - val_loss: 0.4619 - val_accuracy: 0.1727
Epoch 3/5
163/163 [==============================] - 27s 161ms/step - loss: 0.4459 - accuracy: 0.1629 - val_loss: 0.4607 - val_accuracy: 0.1727
Epoch 4/5
163/163 [==============================] - 27s 161ms/step - loss: 0.4458 - accuracy: 0.1629 - val_loss: 0.4602 - val_accuracy: 0.1727
Epoch 5/5
163/163 [==============================] - 29s 173ms/step - loss: 0.4458 - accuracy: 0.1629 - val_loss: 0.4599 - val_accuracy: 0.1727
{'loss': [0.5340373516082764, 0.4476817846298218, 0.44589340686798096, 0.4458162784576416, 0.4458373486995697], 'accuracy': [0.16290727257728577, 0.16290727257728577, 0.16290727257728577, 0.16290727257728577, 0.16290727257728577], 'val_loss': [0.4639807343482971, 0.46193835139274597, 0.4607209861278534, 0.4601666331291199, 0.45988813042640686], 'val_accuracy': [0.1727062463760376, 0.1727062463760376, 0.1727062463760376, 0.1727062463760376, 0.1727062463760376]}
```

As you can see the accuracy remains fixed irrespective of higher or lower epochs.

I have tried with a maximum of 20 epochs and minimum of 5.

I have also tried it with SGD optimizer i.e.,:

```
from keras.optimizers import SGD
opt = SGD(lr=0.01)

model1 = googlenet(input_shape, n_classes)
model1.compile(optimizer = opt, loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
model1.summary()
```

But still the result is same where the accuracy gets stuck at 0.1629.

I have even tried it with even other models like ResNet. But getting the same result.

Does this have something to do with my data preprocessing?

I have my dataset i.e., the images divided already into three folders/directories: **Train, Test and Validation** each in turn contain two sub-folders/directories **class_a, class_b** each contains the images of their respective class.

My preprocessing code is as given below:

```
import numpy as np

data1 = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('Train', shuffle=True)     # Building data pipeline
data2 = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('Test', shuffle=True)     # Building data pipeline
data3 = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('Validation', shuffle=True)     # Building data pipeline
data_iterator1 = data1.as_numpy_iterator()        # Helps in accessing data pipeline
data_iterator2 = data2.as_numpy_iterator()
data_iterator3 = data3.as_numpy_iterator()
batch1 = data_iterator1.next()            # Accessing data pipeline
batch2 = data_iterator2.next() 
batch3 = data_iterator3.next() 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
for idx, img in enumerate(batch1[0][:4]):
    ax[idx].imshow(img.astype(int))
    ax[idx].title.set_text(batch1[1][idx])
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
for idx, img in enumerate(batch2[0][:4]):
    ax[idx].imshow(img.astype(int))
    ax[idx].title.set_text(batch2[1][idx])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
for idx, img in enumerate(batch3[0][:4]):
    ax[idx].imshow(img.astype(int))
    ax[idx].title.set_text(batch3[1][idx])

# Scaling Data
data1 = data1.map(lambda x,y: (x/255, y))
data1.as_numpy_iterator().next()[0].max()

data2 = data2.map(lambda x,y: (x/255, y))
data2.as_numpy_iterator().next()[0].max()

data3 = data3.map(lambda x,y: (x/255, y))
data3.as_numpy_iterator().next()[0].max()

train_size = int(len(data1))
val_size = int(len(data3))
test_size = int(len(data2))

train = data1.take(train_size)
val = data3.take(val_size)
test = data2.take(test_size)
```

Can somebody please help.

Edit: Used dropout of 0.4 and found the same problem of constant accuracy but at 0.8371.

Comment: Perhaps increase the learning rate to 0.1 and see what happens

Comment: Thank You @desert_ranger but I have already tried it. But, even though the accuracy is not always fixed at 0.1629, but the deflection from it is very minute. Can you please help?

Comment: It is hard to help, as I don't have a dataset. Can you import a custom dataset using TF and update your code? That way, the community can better help.

Comment: Try removing `activation='relu'` **only** from the ***last*** _inception_block_ right before _AveragePooling2D_.

Comment: What is the order of magnitude of your training data?

Comment: @learner I tried as you said but am still getting constant accuracy but at a different value 0.8371. Please Help

Comment: @GiorgosLivanos the order of magnitude is class_a : 4342 images and class_b : 845 images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you have 1 output node and you apply `softmax` which means that every output of your model for every example that is processed is 1. You can read more on `softmax` function [here](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/softmax-layer).
This means that when you try to find the accuracy, the value of it would be close to `845 (class 1) / 5187 (class 0 + class 1)` which is 0,162907268.

In order to fix this you should choose one of the 2 possible soutions.

1. Change `softmax` to `sigmoid` activation function of output layer.
2. Change targets to one-hot encoding and set `n_classes = 2` as they would be represented in targets after one-hot encoding.

Comment: thank you so much for sparing your time and effort to answer my question. But Sir unfortunately even after trying with sigmoid function, I am getting the same error. But regarding the number of classes, I can't use n_classes=2 as my class count starts from 0. Can you please help?

Comment: It doesn't matter the number you start count but rather the total number of classes. If your targets are zeroes and ones the you have 2 classes. I would suggest you to change the output to 2 nodes, apply softmax and onehot encoder y_true.